# Add multiple records of Custom object Book using standard Controller and Extensions . I am not getting the output as expected

Tags: apex, visualforce

While trying to add multiple records on my Custom object Book using standard Controller and extension . While clicking on the submit button records are not inserted . 
Could you please check at my extension Logic and do the needful !!
Even my User Interface is not showing the name field is required . (I mean Book Name )

#### Visual Force Page

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" standardController="Book__c" extensions="addMultipleBooksExtension">
<apex:form id="formId">
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockSection >
<apex:inputField value="{!Book__c.Name}" />
<apex:inputField value="{!Book__c.Title__c}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!Book__c.Author__c}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!Book__c.Price__c}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
<apex:commandButton value="Add one more Book" action="{!addBook}" />
<apex:commandButton value="Save your Records" action="{!saveBookRecords}"/>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

---

#### Page Extension

```
public with sharing class addMultipleBooksExtension {

    public list<Book__c> listBook{get;set;}

    public addMultipleBooksExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    list<Book__c> listBook= new list<Book__c>();
    }

  public void addBook(){
      Book__c book= new Book__c() ;
      listBook = new list<BooK__c>();
      listBook.add(book);
  }

  public PageReference saveBookRecords(){
      listBook = new list<Book__c>();
      Integer i ;
      for (i=0 ; i < listBook.size();i++){
      insert listBook;
      }
      return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're clearing the list each time you add a new book, and your save method also creates a new list, which wipes out the previous work; it causes all the input to be lost.

Here's a working version of your controller:

```
public class addMultipleBooksExtension {
    public list<Book__c> listBook{get;set;}

    public addMultipleBooksExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        listBook= new list<Book__c>();
    }

  public void addBook(){
      listBook.add(new Book__c());
  }

  public void saveBookRecords(){
    upsert listBook;
  }
}
```

Comment: Visualforce Error
Help for this Page

System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
Error is in expression '{!addBook}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page addmultiplebookstolibrary: Class.addMultipleBooksExtension.addBook: line 10, column 1

Class.addMultipleBooksExtension.addBook: line 10, column 1

Comment: Visualforce Error
Help for this Page

System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
Error is in expression '{!addBook}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page addmultiplebookstolibrary: Class.addMultipleBooksExtension.addBook: line 10, column 1

Class.addMultipleBooksExtension.addBook: line 10, column 1

Comment: i tried to use your code but it is showing the above mentioned error..

Comment: @Tawseef Sorry, I missed a variable shadowing effect. Try the new updated version.

Comment: still not working ,, can u please try to run there and check ...

Comment: @Tawseef Could you define "not working?" Your page controller is simplistic, so there's no real "success" message you'd expect. Assuming you don't see an error, the records would save successfully.