# Create Multiple Tasks from Contact in VF Page

Tags: visualforce, activities

I am trying to create a VF Page using the Contact object as the controller, but the page will actually be used as a list button on the Activity related list for the Contact record.  I want the user to be able to click this button and present them with a VF page that gives them the ability to create multiple tasks at once.  I know what I want the VF page to look like and I know I will need a custom controller to create the tasks, but I'm struggling on 1) how to create multiple tasks in a single VF page, and 2) What the controller needs to look like to reference the Activity object from the Contact object.  Can anyone provide guidance or an example link of something similar?  I am in the planing stage for this so I don't have any code to share.  Thanks,

Comment: You can create one or many records from a controller.  They don't have to be objects of the same type as the controller handles.   You wouldn't necessarily need to have a second page for creating the tasks as long as you put fields in the VF page to give you the info you need to create the task.  Fields in the VF page don't have to correspond to fields in the object.

Comment: @Jagular -- Thanks.  Do you have any links to examples of how I can do that?  Thanks.

Comment: Here is a very simple example: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000095ONIAY  Note that the records are created in the constructor and saved via the button.  Creating them in the constructor is almost certainly not how you would want to do it (because you'd need info from the VF page).

Comment: There's also this: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/68120/add-multiple-records-of-custom-object-book-using-standard-controller-and-extensi